# How to properly test a Flink window function?

Tags: testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Does anyone know how to test windowing functions in `Flink`? I am using the dependency `flink-test-utils_2.11`.

My steps are:

1. Get the `StreamExecutionEnvironment`
2. Create objects and add to the invironment
3. Do a `keyBy`
4. add a Session Window
5. execute an aggregate function

```
public class AggregateVariantCEVTest extends AbstractTestBase {

   @Test
    public void testAggregateVariantCev() throws Exception  {
       StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
       env.setParallelism(1);

       env.fromElements(objectOne, objectTwo)
               .keyBy(new KeyedByMyCustomKey())
               .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(1)))
               .aggregate(new MyAgreggateFunction());


       JobExecutionResult result = env.execute();

       assertEquals(myExpectedResults, result.getAllAccumulatorResults());

   }
}
```

The problem is that `result.getAllAccumulatorResults()` size is 0.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Windows don't put their results into accumulators. You should attach a test sink to your job and then compare that sink's contents to what you expect. Something like what's shown in the documentation in the [section on integration testing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#integration-testing).

Comment: I've added a CollectSink based on the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#junit-rule-miniclusterwithclientresource) , but it the result is not in the there. Am I missing someting? Thanks!

Comment: Could be, but I can't guess what. Can you ask a new question, and show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the right approach here is to use a `TestHarness`. A good example is the `WindowOperatorTest` in the Flink project itself.

Furthermore, you can checkout https://github.com/knaufk/flink-testing-pyramid for examples how to test Flink Job on different levels of the testing pyramid and the Flink documentation on testing https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/testing.html.