# Testing Flink with embedded Kafka

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, integration-testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple Flink application, which sums up the events with the same id and timestamp within the last minute:

```
DataStream<String> input = env
                .addSource(consumerProps)
                .uid("app");

DataStream<Event> events = input.map(record -> mapper.readValue(record, Event.class));

pixels
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampsAndWatermarks())
        .keyBy("id")
        .timeWindow(Time.minutes(1))
        .sum("constant")
        .addSink(simpleNotificationServiceSink);


env.execute(jobName);


private static class TimestampsAndWatermarks extends BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Pixel> {
        public TimestampsAndWatermarks() {
            super(Time.seconds(90));
        }

        // timestampReadable is timestamp rounded on minutes, in format yyyyMMddhhmm
        @Override
        public long extractTimestamp(Pixel pixel) {
            return Long.parseLong(pixel.timestampReadable);
        }
    }
```

I would like to implement the scenario:

1. Start embedded Kafka
2. Publish couple of messages to the topic
3. Consume the messages with Flink
4. Check the correctness of the output produced by Flink

Does Flink provides utilities to test the job with embedded Kafka? If yes, what is the recommended approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JUnit rule you can use to bring up an embedded Kafka -- see (see https://github.com/charithe/kafka-junit).

To have tests that terminate cleanly, try something like this:

```java
public class TestDeserializer extends YourKafkaDeserializer<T> {
  public final static String END_APP_MARKER = "END_APP_MARKER"; // tests send as last record

  @Override
  public boolean isEndOfStream(ParseResult<T> nextElement) {
    if (nextElement.getParseError() == null)
      return false;

    if (END_APP_MARKER.equals(nextElement.getParseError().getRawData()))
      return true;

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend (test containers)[https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/] as that can also be used for other resources. I usually combine that with https://mguenther.github.io/kafka-junit/ to create topics and add/read data.

Comment: Can someone point me to an example of using testcontainers in a test relying on Kafka as the one described by the OP?

Comment: @salvalcantara If you search in the Flink sources, you'll find testcontainers has been used there a little bit. `https://github.com/search?q=testcontainers+flink+kafka&type=code` has a bunch of hits -- you can probably find something helpful in there.

Comment: Thanks David, these are great examples!